# Eslint not fixing semicolons in JSX

Tags: javascript, lint, jsx, eslint

I'm using the following packages:

```
"eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.0",
"eslint-config-standard-react": "^4.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^6.4.0",
"eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
```

With the following .eslintrc` config:

```
{
  "parser"  : "babel-eslint",
  "extends" : [
    "standard",
    "standard-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel",
    "react",
    "promise"
  ],
  "env"     : {
    "browser" : true
  },
  "globals" : {
    "__DEV__"             : false,
    "__PROD__"            : false,
    "__DEBUG__"           : false,
    "__COVERAGE__"        : false,
    "__BASENAME__"        : false
  },
  "rules": {
    "key-spacing" : [2, {
      "singleLine" : {
        "beforeColon" : false,
        "afterColon"  : true
      },
      "multiLine" : {
        "mode"        : "strict",
        "beforeColon" : false,
        "afterColon"  : true
      }
    }],
    "babel/generator-star-spacing" : 1,
    "generator-star-spacing"       : 0,
    "jsx-quotes"                   : [2, "prefer-single"],
    "max-len"                      : [2, 120, 2],
    "object-curly-spacing"         : [2, "always"],
    "comma-dangle"                 : [2, "always-multiline"]
  }
}
```

This config is somehow ignoring the semicolons in JSX files: it does not remove them while running lint fix from the end of the lines in the JSX but it does in the JS. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?